# How do I set the radio button to "checked" in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap buttons as a radio button.  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

This is my current code:

```
<div  class="btn-group col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-gender btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female"> Girls
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-gender btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male"> Guys
    </label>
</div>
```

How can I set "male" to checked using JavaScript?

Comment: I'm having the same question, and it is a bootstrap rendering question.  The code in the answers may set the radio state, but they don't change the bootstrap visuals.  I think the current answers miss the mark, not taking bootstrap into consideration.  Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanN/ba7d24k3/  I am endeavoring to find an answer, I will give the question a bump in the meantime.

Comment: Added a new question based on this one with my answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296686/is-this-the-right-way-to-set-the-radio-button-to-checked-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

Since the `male` is a `value` attribute, use:

```
document.querySelector("input[value='male']").checked = true;
```

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you change the id, correspond to each gender, so you can apply js like below:

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("gender-male").checked = true;
}
function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("gender-male").checked = false;
}
```

OR, if you want to set it as checked by default, then you can use HTML 5 attribute, like below:

```
<label class="btn btn-info">
    <input checked type="radio" id="match-three" name="options">Three numbers
</label>
```

Check out this question: [bootstrap-set-initial-radio-button-checked-in-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541484/bootstrap-set-initial-radio-button-checked-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

**Html :**

```
<div  class="btn-group col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-gender btn-default active">
                        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female"> Girls
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-gender btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male"> Guys
                    </label>
                </div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
function check() {
    document.getElementById("male").checked = true;
}
```