# Is this the right way to set the radio button to “checked” in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am repurposing TIMEX's question that's been marked as duplicate, because I believe it is not a duplicate and I hit the same issue.

[How do I set the radio button to "checked" in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463822/how-do-i-set-the-radio-button-to-checked-in-bootstrap)

> I'm using Bootstrap buttons as a radio button.
>   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons
>
> This is my current code:
>
> ```
> <div  class="btn-group col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
>     <label class="btn btn-gender btn-default active">
>         <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female"> Girls
>     </label>
>     <label class="btn btn-gender btn-default">
>         <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male"> Guys
>     </label> 
> </div>
> ```
>
> How can I set "male" to checked using JavaScript?

Here's my reproduction of the problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanN/ba7d24k3/

I couldn't find a solution in the getbootstrap.com documentation or readily on stackoverflow, so here's what I came up with:
https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanN/ba7d24k3/2/

```
var toggleRadioButton = function ($parent, name, value) {
  var $allButtons = $parent.find('input[name="' + name + '"]');
  $allButtons.prop('checked', false);
  $allButtons.parents('label.btn').removeClass('active');
  var $targetButton = $parent.find('input[name="' + name + '"][value="' + value + '"]');
  $targetButton.prop('checked', true);
  $targetButton.parents('label.btn').addClass('active');
};
```

I used jQuery, but it could be coded up in more verbose javascript as well.  Hopefully I've established that is not a duplicate of the basic how to set a radio button with javascript question.

My question: Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do something like

> `$parent.find('input[name="' + name + '"][value="' + value + '"]').click();`

to trigger a click event for whichever radio option you want selected? This way bootstrap can handle all the CSS class changes and such.

Comment: Appears to work.  I'll take it if nothing better comes along... :) https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanN/ba7d24k3/4/

Comment: At the least, it is more flexible code. If they update bootstrap it most likely won't break.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a bootstrap way to do it.

```
$('#genderM').parents('.btn').button('toggle');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanN/ba7d24k3/5/